# Textbooks on solidifying graduate knowledge

Tags: reference-request, big-list

I am finishing my undergraduate program soon and start getting ready for graduate school. What I have realized is that although I have passed many subjects and with good grades I feel that mathematical knowledge is somewhat loose.

I am looking for books/textbooks that aim on "solidifying" my body of knowledge. For example, I found the books *Geometry I & II* by Marcel Berger a very nice way to use very basic facts about groups and vector spaces to study very intricate things (+it contains *many* excersises). Other books I have in mind (although I have read a small portion of them) are the books of Terrence Tao with excerpts from his blog. Or yet another example, the (somewhat old) book of Shlomo Sternberg on Calculus (since it provides a very concrecte organisation of a syllabus spanning 3 or more subjects in a standard undergraduate program).

Alternatively, sets of demanding problems (like those provided by Paul Siegel) are very, very welcome.

Let me state in another way my question: What are the books you wished you have read as an undergraduate. And since there are many Proffesors here: What are the books you wished your graduate students have read?

Comment: If I could do it all over again I would probably read fewer books and solve more problems.  And not just exercises in textbooks; problems like these: https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.0290

Comment: Amazingly, as someone with love for geometry, this is just what I was looking for!

Comment: The set of books will depend on the broad area which you want to study in graduate school.Mathematics is so large that some specialization at this stage is inevitable. If you are going to study in the US, look at the subjects of "qualifying examinations" required in the school you apply. This will tell you in what areas you have to "solidify your knowledge" first of all.

Comment: This was easier in the first half of 20th century when a French multi-volume "Course d'Analyse" or a Russian analog "Course of Higher Mathematics" could be recommended. But this is not the case anymore.

Comment: Not sure what's the best textbook, but I would know linear algebra like the back of your hand. I've always used Friedberg (which has many exercises) but there may be better options. You probably have the basics of vector spaces down, but go further. Get extremely familiar with dual spaces and the significance of transposes and adjoints. Also overarching themes about invariant subspaces. Also draw connections with more general algebraic structures.